# How to correctly validate data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to validate my model data which is a text box for string entry but when I try to test with int entry, I get no error and it is saved to the database ...

How can I prevent this?

Model class:

```
[Required]
public string DeptName { get; set; }
```

Action method:

```
public ActionResult Update(Dept model)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }

        db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

View:

```
@model Dept

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.DeptId);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.DeptName);
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.DeptName);
    <input value="Update" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" />
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[RegularExpression("[a-zA-Z]*", ErrorMessage = "Cannot be a number")]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use only [Required] attribute then its check the value empty or not, It's no check the value type int or string.

If you want to allow the only alphabet characters in a textbox.
you can use the regular expression

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
string DeptName {get; set;}
```